# Get specific div from a page on same website

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am using wordpress.

I have a page ony my website called www.mywebsite.com/test , on this page I have a div with a class 'newtest'.

I wish to pull that div and have it show on my other pages on the same website using a PHP code.

I have found a code on stackoverflow that is very close to what I want to accomplish.

This is the original code that I found:

```
   <?php
   $url = "http://www.timeanddate.com/weather/";
   $page_all = file_get_contents($url); 
   preg_match('#<table class="border2 lpad wa">(.*)</table>#ms', $page_all, $div_array);
   echo "<pre>";
   print_r($div_array[0]);
   echo "</pre>";
   ?>
```

I used it, and nothing showed.

I ended up changing the 'table class' to 'div class' and I got SOME results that did end up pulling that specific div, but boy did it messed up my page..

Is there something I can modify to the code above to pull that specific div?

Comment: Why not use an include?

Comment: Its a little complex, you see I use a Divi designer which is user friendly.. it helps to created what I want easily, and gives me the ability to change it in the future.. I am going to insert this div in many pages, and it would be nice not to have to go through ALL the pages to make edits.. I would use the include but it has to be pulled by div class or div name..

Answer (score 0):

Create a new folder somwhere in your project called for example "Resources" and place a new php-file with only the div code inside.

Resources/adiv.php contains`<div class="foo"><h1>I'am a div</h1></div>`

So now you can include this file in there where you want the div.

Somwhere in a file:

```
<?php include('Resources/adiv.php'); ?>
```

Comment: Its a little complex, you see I use a Divi designer which is user friendly.. it helps to created what I want easily, and gives me the ability to change it in the future.. I am going to insert this div in many pages, and it would be nice not to have to go through ALL the pages to make edits.. I would use the include but it has to be pulled by div class or div name..

Comment: For me it worked, but i don't how it is with Wordpress :/

Comment: No yeah I get ya, this is the easy way.. But it requires to know what you are doing I guess (creating/designing the div)... I have a program that generates/designs all the things I want, so its much easier to create without having to know much code.. all I need to do is pull that div that the program creates lol